# Can jquery detect when an outside software finished loading

Tags: python, php, jquery

My code interacts with 2 separate software.Software 2 can not work if software 1 is not finished loading. So, i want to see if there's a way my code can detect when the first software finished loading completely before opening software 2.

My code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(event){

 ....

    //Open fist software
      $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type:"POST",
        success: function(data) {
          //alert("File 1 Completed")

            $("#progress-text").text("Opening first software");
            $('#progBar').val(25);

            
            $.ajax({
              url: "ajax2.php",
              type:"POST",
                success: function(data2) {
                  //alert("File 2 Completed")
                  $("#progress-text").text("Opening second software");
                  $('#progBar').val(50);

                  //Start of 3rd script
                  $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax3.php",
                    type:"POST",
                      success: function(data3) {
                        //alert("File 2 Completed")
                         $("#progress-text").text("Complete");
                         $('#progBar').val(100);

                      }
                  });
                }
            });
          }
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

ajax.php: executes a python file, which opens the 1st software

ajax2.php: excutes a python file, which opens the 2nd software

ajax3.php: sleeps for 4 sec.

The problem is is that when jquery executes ajax.php it opens the software but does not wait for it to load completely before moving to ajax2.php. Can i solve this issue directly or would it have to be done in the python side?

Comment: AJAX will respond to what it gets from the server call it made. If that server call returns too early, then yes, the problem will be with python returning too early. You would either need to open a websocket (or use a service), or short-poll your own server multiple times to see if the software that was supposed to load up, is finally loaded up.

Comment: ajax2 won't run until you echo a response for ajax1

Comment: The other option is make the python script wait and loop itself checking before it responds back to the ajax call. However this could present an overrun situation... serious lag times... timeouts. And you would have to account for that. And if this is something that MANY multiple users would be hitting, it could just crash your environment.